# Why can't I add a count to my onclick function?

Tags: javascript, css, onclick

I wanted to try using a count to change the behavior of a click. All my other conditions worked but I don't understand why my count condition doesn't. Does anyone know what I can do to make it work?

For the count I tried -- (this.count == 2), (count == 2), and (uh.count == 2)

```js
function uh() {
  var words;
  var conf = confirm("ooh that felt goood");
  var button = document.querySelector("#selector");
  var box =
    document.querySelector("#box");
  var count = 0;
  if (this.count == 5) {
    button.classname = "button3";
    words = " ";
  } else if (this.count == 4) {
    button.classname = "button3";
    words = "I give up. This is all you get.";
    count++;
  } else if (this.count == 3) {
    button.classname = "button3";
    words = "...";
    count++;
  } else if (this.count == 2) {
    button.className = "button2";
    words = "the power?";
    count++;
  } else if (button.className == "button3") {
    button.className = "button2";
    words = "ahahaha... ha.. uh..";
    count++;
  } else if (button.className == "button2") {
    button.className = "button3";
    box.className = "box";
    words = "THE POWER";
  } else if (conf == true) {
    words = "AHAHAHA I HAVE YOU NOW";
    button.className = "button2";
  } else {
    words = "...";
    button.className = "button";
  }
  document.querySelector(".header").innerHTML = words;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

#header {
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  background-color: #000099;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px solid white;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 90%;
}

#box {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
  height: 500px;
}

.box {
  text-align: center;
  height: 500px;
}

.button {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  margin: 170px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.button2 {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  margin: 170px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px white;
}

.button3 {
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
  color: red;
  padding: 30px 60px;
  margin: 170px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 60px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 5px gold;
}
```

```html
<div id=h eader>
  <h1 class="header"> I feel an itch...
    <h1>
</div>
<div id="box">
  <input type="button" id="selector" class="button" value="CLICK ME" onclick="uh()">
</div>
```

Comment: Your function initializes the local variable `count` to zero each time it's called. Simplest thing to do is declare `count` *outside* the function.

Comment: `this.count` ???

Comment: Yeah, do not stick it inside the function.

Comment: Also it should be referred to as simply `count`, not `this.count`.

Comment: @epascarello aren't functions objects?

Comment: @epascarello Oh right! Okay thanks

Comment: @Pointy that's what I had at first but I started to doubt myself when it wasn't working

Comment: You must declare the `count` variable outside of the function and make sure to apply a count++ each time the function is executed !

Comment: This kind of looks like you could just put all the sentences inside an array and keep popping or shifting the next sentence. Unless the user clicks `yes` for `conf`, the script does not do anything meaningful since the className starts at `button` and the count at `0`, both of which do not lead to a different path. So if you remove those you are left with the paths that do count++ until the end, which basically is an array.

Comment: @Shilly Really great idea, thank you. I was wondering how I could do something like that and ofc an array *facepalm*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count` is declared and initialized anew each time `uh()` is called. The variable lifetime ends when the function ends so there is no way to preserve its value across multiple calls to `uh()`.

What you could do, is declare an object called `count` with a same name property and `call()` `uh` on the object. Then `this` will refer to the object `uh()` gets called on and thus `this.count` will have a transferable value across multiple calls on the same object.

```
var count = {count: 0};

console.log(count.count);//0

up.call(count);

function up() {

this.count++;
//... here add any kind of check on the value of count
}

console.log(count.count);//1
```